# jQuery & Ajax: catching a 500

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery code that send an Ajax request on a form submit. My issue is I can't catch timeout error using that code. When I send a 500 response myself it is working but if I get a timeout then I see 500 in the console but nothing happens, the error callback is not executed. Instead I get :

> SyntaxError: syntax error

On the line:

> $(document).ready(function(){

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('submit', 'form#myForm', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert('success!');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('error!');
            }
        });
        return false;       
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `dataType: 'json'`? It sounds like jquery is barfing trying to parse a text-only timeout response as JSON.

Comment: You nailed it @AndrewLorente Thanks! I should have thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting that the server is throwing a 500 and the "error" callback is not being called. To further investigate this issue add a "complete" callback to the ajax call and a timeout value:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 5000, 
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('success!');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error!');
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            alert(textStatus); // this could be 'timeout'
         }
    });
```

The complete callback is called after the request finishes; after "success" and "error". The textStatus parameter of the complete callback will be a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). This should give us you some further information on exactly what jquery is doing with the request.

Comment: The response body from the server is completly empty. So it could not be parsed as a JSON like described. That was the mistake. Finnaly removed that option and let jQuery guessed the data type like @AndrewLorente suggested. And it works like a charm. Thanks for your help anyway! Much appreciate.

Comment: That makes sense. We should post @AndrewLorente 's solution as an answer then

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but you can set the timeout of the ajax query to match you server, or be slightly less, and trap it, then check the textStatus.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 3000, //3 Seconds
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('success!');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
            alert('Failed from timeout');
            //do something. 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The solution was to remove the dataType like @AndrewLorente suggested.